# How to populate a dynamically added dropdownlist from a stronglyTyped Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

A lot of questions on SO are about *using Ajax data to populate dropdownsList.*

But, *I already have the data in a strongly typed model* that contains `SelectList` items. I want to use that to fill my dropdownlist - how do I do this?

So, after *adding a new row to a table with a dropdownlist*, **how to populate/bind the newly cloned `dropDownList`** from the **data in the** `cities Model`.

```
// List of cities in my Model, Location
LocationModel {
...
IEnumerable<City> Cities }
```

Cloned row: and in **my view** I cloned a row

```
<table id="rowtemplate">
 <tr>
   <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="#" />
        <span class="citiesCss">
          //DropDownList to clone
            <select class="form-control citiesCssId" id="Records_[#]__SelectedCityFromList" name="Records[#].SelectedCityFromList">
                <option value="">Default</option>                
            </select>
     </span>
   </td>

   <td> ... another cell       
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

**How can I bind/populate the newly cloned dropdown** from the `CityList model` values?

```
    $("#CloneButton").click(function () {
        var index = (new Random());
        var clone = $('#rowtemplate').clone();
        clone.html($(clone).html());
        clone.find('.cities').text(cities);            
        $('#MainTable').append(clone.find('tr'));
    });
```

Comment: If the data is in your model, why are you not just creating the options in the select when it is first generated so that cloning it copies the options as well?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I am not following,  How can I access the model, to clone its values? Since, the drop downs are added *inAdd New Row* after the view is rendered from server, so its on client side. So, this is *not* possible `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCity, Model.City, "", new { @class = "form-control" })` .

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you saying create a `hidden DropDown` and then `clone` that

Comment: In your template, you could just do `<select .... >@foreach(var item in yourCollection) { <option value="@item.xx">@item.yy</option> }</select>` so the options are cloned as well (and note that you really do not need to add the `id` attribute to your elements)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes this was total genius, and this was the answer, I can mark it as answer. Once again you have the simplest and best answers - by that I mean its easy to maintain as well :)

Comment: Your also missing the code to update the html of the template - to replace the `#` with the value of `index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138436/discussion-between-transformer-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create the options in your template based on your collection when the view is generated. Assuming `City`contains properties `Id` and `Name`, then

```
<table id="rowtemplate">
    ....
    <select class="form-control citiesCssId" name="Records[#].SelectedCityFromList">
        <option value="">Default</option>
        @foreach(var city in Model.Cities)
        {
            <option value="@city.Id">@city.Name</option>
        }              
    </select>
    ....
</table>
```

Now when you use `var clone = $('#rowtemplate').clone();` to copy the template, the value of `clone` also includes the `<option>` elements